# Как сделать отступы между radiobuton?

Tags: css, html5

Каким образом сделать отступы между radiobutton компонентами?
Что бы отступ не лейбла от радиокнопки был, а именно
radiobutton label потом отступ на n количество пикселей и опять radiobutton label
У меня сейчас вот так сделано, и не могу понять как отступы сделать.
Неужели каждый компонент надо в свой div обернуть?

```css
.container{
    width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="radiobuttons">
    <input type="radio" checked name="ps4" id="ps4"/>
    <label for="ps4">PlayStation 4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ps4" id="xbox"/>
    <label for="xbox">Xbox One</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```css
.container{
    width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.radiobuttons input[type='radio'] + label:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="radiobuttons">
    <input type="radio" checked name="ps4" id="ps4"/>
    <label for="ps4">PlayStation 4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ps4" id="xbox"/>
    <label for="xbox">Xbox One</label>
    </div>
</div>
```